# How to rearrange data from a set of columns to another set of columns in excel?

Tags: vba, excel

Hey so I'm new to VBA and I'm trying to move data from a column to another column in a different format in the same worksheet. 
So the original data looks like this:

```
  Type   Fx Fy Fz
1  DL     1  2  3 
1  LL     4  5  6
1  C1     7  8  9
1  C2    10  11 12
2  DL    5   6  7
2  LL    6   8  4
2  C1    3   3  4
2  C2    1   2  3
```

I want to arrange this to another set of columns with a format similar to this:

```
       DL            LL             C1            C2
   Fx  Fy  Fz    Fx  Fy  Fz     Fz  Fy  Fz    Fx  Fy  Fz
1   1  2    3     4   5   6      7   8   9    10  11  12 
2   5   6   7     6   8   4      3   3   4    1    2   3
```

I tried doing record macro for this and this is what the code looked like:

```
   Sub Macro2()
       Selection.Copy
        ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 7).Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveCell.Offset(2, -5).Range("A1:C1").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 6).Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveCell.Offset(3, -6).Range("A1:C1").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        ActiveCell.Offset(-3, 9).Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveCell.Offset(4, -9).Range("A1:C1").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        ActiveCell.Offset(-4, 12).Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveCell.Offset(5, -12).Range("A1:C1").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        ActiveCell.Offset(-5, 15).Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveCell.Offset(6, -17).Range("A1").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        ActiveCell.Offset(-5, 7).Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveCell.Offset(5, -5).Range("A1:C1").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        ActiveCell.Offset(-5, 6).Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveCell.Offset(6, -6).Range("A1:C1").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        ActiveCell.Offset(-6, 9).Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveCell.Offset(7, -9).Range("A1:C1").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        ActiveCell.Offset(-7, 12).Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveCell.Offset(8, -12).Range("A1:C1").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        ActiveCell.Offset(-8, 15).Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End Sub
```

Comment: Have you considered using a pivot table instead of hard coded macro reformatting?

Comment: Also, what is your question?

Comment: Are the `1` and `2` in your source actually part of the data?

Comment: Never used a pivot table will try it....My question is to convert the format of source 1 into the format of source 2.

Comment: and 1& 2 is actually typed by me... tried copying and pasting but it had a weird format so I just handwritten everything

Comment: just used pivot table and realized it does not what I want it to do. I need to recategorize the column... not a sum of it

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub moveit()

    Dim src As Worksheet, dest As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range, f As Range

    Set src = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set dest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    dest.UsedRange.ClearContents 'start with empty sheet

    Set c = src.Range("a2")
    Do While Len(c.Value) > 0

        Set f = dest.Rows(1).Find(c.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If f Is Nothing Then
            Set f = dest.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
            If Len(f.Value) > 0 Then Set f = f.Offset(0, 3)
            f.Value = c.Value
            src.Range("B1:D1").Copy f.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
        c.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 3).Copy dest.Cells(Rows.Count, f.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)

    Loop


End Sub
```